# NaN error in React when I'm trying to use the useState hook in different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make app that will take the value of input element and use this value in inc/dec component. I have 2 components and I use props.

1. Component have input and a set button.
2. Component have inc/dec buttons and reset button

I'm enter number to first component set it with button. Then I want to inc/dec it in second component and I have NaN error. When I reset it the element take the value of first component and after that inc/dec works well.

**first component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Sample from "../Sample/Sample";

const SetSample = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const formChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const handlerChange = () => {
        const foo = document.querySelector("input").value * 1;
        setValue(foo);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={formChange}>
                <input type="text" />
                <button type="submit" onClick={handlerChange}>Set start value</button>
            </form>
            <p>Start value is: {value || 'Please enter a number'}</p>
            <hr />

            <Sample start={value} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default SetSample;
```

**second component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Sample = (props) => {
    const point = props.start;
    const [counter = 0, setCounter] = useState(point);


    const decrement = () => {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
    }
    const increment = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
    const reset = () => {
        setCounter(point);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
            <div>{counter}</div>
            <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
            <div><button onClick={reset}>reset</button></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sample;
```

It seems to me that the problem is in counter and point values.

Comment: How many `<input>` elements do you have in the DOM of the page *after* all your components have rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to import `useEffect` hook from react, then in the dependency array, you have to enter your point variable.

Nothing interacts with your `Sample.jsx` after you click `Set Start Value`.

And when you click the `reset` button there is some interaction.

Due to that and you are able to see the number only after clicking `reset`.

```
import React, { useState , useEffect } from "react";
const Sample = (props) => {
    const point = props.start;
    const [counter = 0, setCounter] = useState(point);

    // edited here
    useEffect(()=>{
      setCounter(props.start);
    },[point]);

    const decrement = () => {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
    }
    const increment = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
    const reset = () => {
        setCounter(point);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
            <div>{counter}</div>
            <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
            <div><button onClick={reset}>reset</button></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default Sample;

Comment: Thank you very much. Need to learn more I did even know what is useEffect hook is.

Answer (score 0):

In the first render you need to set the value of the input to be 0 just not to run into `NaN` error in `SetSample` component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

and in Sample component you need to set the counter if it changes using `useEffect` and don't set 0 for it because it already has 0 from `props.start`:

```
const point = props.start;
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(point);

useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(point);
}, [point]);
```

Comment: Thnk you for your help!!!